# Draw circle in TableLayout Android

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I can draw circle in full activity with `addContentView`. But I would draw in TableLayout. I added the class for drawing in `TableLayout` addView. But the codes doesn't work. I can't draw in `TableLayout`. I find this codes:

```
TableLayout tlayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
TableRow trow = new TableRow(this);

trow.add(new cizim(this));
trow.add(new cizim(this));
trow.add(new cizim(this));

tlayout.addView(trow);
```

cizim is my draw class. This code work. But I have 10 table row and 10 `TaxtView` in each table row in xml layout. I deleted table rows in `TableLayout` and I added cizim class in table rows. After I added table rows in `TableLayout`. But only the first table row seems that. And can't draw.

How can I resolve this problem?

I need your help.